# If $F$ is a field and $F_1$ is a subfield of $F$, then $F$ is vector space over $F_1$.

Tags: vector-spaces

> Prove: If $F$ is a field and $F_1$ is a subfield of $F$, then $F$ is vector space over $F_1$.

Comment: It's really obvious ! The definition is more or less the proof (sorry if it sounds a bit arrogant, but it's really the case). Where do you get stuck ?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a vector space over an arbitrary field? You just need to check that $F$ satisfies it.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! "Isolated problem statements" are discouraged here. Please always try to include your thoughts on a question, and or to convey some idea of where you got stuck. Such information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know. (Plus, it helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.)

Comment: In fact you do this by ignoring some of the structure in $F$, which is why it can seem confusing - the definition of a vector space highlights what is important. Although this ignoring information seems counterintuitive, actually it can be a very helpful way of looking at things - it illuminates the structure of finite fields, for example, and it helps us to understand just how one field can sit inside another.

Comment: @Surb it's ok..... I got it

Answer (score 0):

Let X be a field.

Let K be an extension field of X. ie X is a subfield of K.

We know that K is a vector space over itself.

Since X is a subfield of K, we have associativity and distributivity for between all elements in X and all elements in K. Therefore every element in X can be used as a scalar.

I think you may be confused as to the terminology.

We have a vector space over some field. This field is used for scalar multiplication. I mentioned but did not elaborate, that a field over itself is a vector space. If you take this part as true and understood, then intuitively any subfield of that field can also be used.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

If $F$ is a field, we know it is closed to addition.
and because $K\subseteq F$ we know that any scalar $t\in K$ is also $t\in F$ and when multiplying a vector $a\in F$ by a scalar $t\in K$ it is like multiplying two elements from the field $a,t\in F$ and because $F$ is a field, it is closed for multiplication. and that applies for any scalar in $K$.

so we see that $F$ as a vector field is closed for addition and multiplication.

we know from $F$ being a field, that it has: associativity for addition, commutativity for addition, a zero identity and  additive inverses. so that covers the first four axioms of a vector field:

1. Associativity of vector addition
2. Commutativity of vector addition
3. Identity element of vector addition
4. Inverse elements of vector addition

For the rest of the axioms:

Lets take an arbitrary vector $x,y \in F$ and an arbitrary scalars $t,k \in K$:
we know that $x,t,k \in F$ and therefore $(t\cdot k)x=t(k\cdot x)$ because the multiplication axioms of a field apply.

we know that $t\cdot (x+y)=t\cdot x+t\cdot y$ and that $(t+k)x=t\cdot x+ k\cdot x$ because all the elements are in $F$ and therefore the distributivity axioms on a field apply here.

Also there exists a element 1 in $K$ such that $1\cdot x = x$. we know that the element 1 exists in $K$ because it is a field (any sub-field is a wield within its own right).

that covers the last axioms of a vector space:

5. Compatibility of scalar multiplication with field multiplication
6. Identity element of scalar multiplication.
7. Distributivity of scalar multiplication with respect to vector addition .
8. Distributivity of scalar multiplication with respect to field addition.

We see that $F$ is a vector space over $K$ because it is closed for addition and multiplication, it has a zero vector and it upholds all the axioms of a vector field.